# "Sorry, this is too big to display."

Tags: github, git-lfs

I uploaded a .ipynb file on github using git lfs but the file is not being displayed. Any ideas on how to fix this?

"Sorry, this is too big to display."

[image: 1]

The option "Include Git LFS objects in archives" in the settings is already active. I tried to find something here but couldn't find any topic with this specific problem. I would like to add this to my portfolio repo. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the file is too large to display in the web view.  The file is 36.8 MB in size, and in order to render that Jupiter Notebook, it would have to be downloaded and rendered, which, due to its size, would probably take substantial resources and might simply time out.

As a result, GitHub is telling you that it's not going to render it because it would likely fail due to timeouts and resource constraints necessary to prevent denial of service attacks.  If you want to display it elsewhere on your own site, you can render it there yourself, but GitHub won't do it for you.